# Input format for scipy.levene

Tags: python

I want to test the homogeneity between several different group samples to using scipy.levene.

```
sample_1 = [1,2,3,4]
sample_2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
sample_3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
from scipy.stats import levene
h, p = levene(sample_1, sample_2, sample_3)
```

I understand that above code works, but how can I put input for levene if I have multiple(undesignated number of) group sample data ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your samples are in a list or some other iterable, you can use arg unpacking to pass an unspecified number of arguments to a function

```
samples = [a, b, c, ...]
levene(*samples)
```

Answer (score 0):

Followed by Iain Shelvington's answer, I solved the problem like this.

```
# group_data is Dict structure with contain different group's sample data(array, list).

def homogeneity_test(group_data):
        return levene(*[group_data[key] for key in group_data.keys()])
```